# How to display XML data in jQueryUI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm fetching XML file using XHR but when I try to display that data in a Dialog, I get following error.

> Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3

Here's the code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        jQuery(".dialog").html(xml);
        jQuery(".dialog").dialog("open");
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: url,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(xml){
        jQuery("dialog").text(xml);
        jQuery("dialog").dialog("open");
    }               
});
```

And applying following style to Dialog did the magic

```
dialog{
    white-space: pre;
}
```